# Adding overall login/password to dev server?

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, authentication

Is there a way to add a stock "authentication required" popup to a dev server in a way that once they've logged in once, they can view the whole dev server?

Our application is built in CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're looking for is Apache Basic Authentication:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/auth.html

(If you're using Apache, but most other servers offer similar support).

It can be a pain to set up and manage, but it's cheap and fast security.

Scroll down to the "Getting it working" bit to get started.

Answer (score 1):

you could just add a basic htpasswd / htaccess restriction to the domain.